# Multiple Dependent Queries

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am trying to perform a first PHP query, then a second query based on the results from the first, and have all the results combined into one array of ID values.

In practice, I want to delete all children and grand children of a parent post. So first I am using the Parent ID **$Work_ID** to query all children **$Phase_Tasks**, then for each returned children **$Phase_Tasks as $Phase_Task** I am querying grandchildren **$Phase_TaskSUBS**.

The problem I am encountering is in managing the arrays, each 'children->grandchildren' query is returning an array so I am trying to use array_merge(), to bring out one final array of IDs sent for deletion.

```
function Array_Test(){

$Work_ID=get_the_ID();

$Phase_Tasks=get_posts(array(
    'fields'    => 'ids',
    'post_type' => 'task',
    'meta_key'      => 'Work_Parent_Phase',
    'meta_value'    => $Work_ID
)); 
    foreach($Phase_Tasks as $Phase_Task){
    
        $Phase_TaskSUBS=array(get_posts(array(
        'fields'    => 'ids',
        'post_type' => 'subtask',
        'meta_key'      => 'Work_Parent_Task',
        'meta_value'    => $Phase_Task
         )));

         $Phase_TaskSUBS_return = array_merge(...$Phase_TaskSUBS); 
}
    $Phase_Tasks_return=$Phase_Tasks;
    return var_dump(array_merge($Phase_TaskSUBS_return,$Phase_Tasks_return)); 
}
```

Currently, this script brings out all children, and only ONE of the grandchildren.
var_dump returns 6 results out of 10, where I have 5 children and 5 grandchildren in total(counting only one of the arrays returned by the foreach children query).

Comment: I think you want `$Phase_TaskSUBS_return = array_merge(Phase_TaskSUBS_return ?? [], $Phase_TaskSUBS);`

Comment: Wow, that worked like magic!

Comment: Could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the right answer just for anyone else coming to this post.

Comment: Your problem was that each time through the `foreach` loop you were overwriting the return value, instead of merging the current results with it.

Comment: This type of question has been asked many times, if you leave it open it will probably just get closed as a duplicate, I would just delete it.

Comment: Oh I see, I searched for it a lot here but I think I missed on using the right search keywords. Thanks a lot again. I will check, if I find a duplicate will delete it.